# как удалить учетную запись пользователя на мак

Tags: macos, mac

Я хочу удалить учетную запись старого владельца, но при удалении через настройки система просит пароль. Прикол в том что пароля нет и не было. Поставил пароль, но говорит что пароль неправильный. Что можно сделать подскажите?